# no me agarra las validaciones en campos de una modal jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

soy nuevo en esto perdonen por lo que estoy poniendo, hice unas validaciones para una modal que contiene varios campos la estoy estoy usando dentro de una tabla y estoy usando una libreria de jquery que es jquery validate, al momento de aplicar las validaciones no me las agarra no se, si la sintaxis es incorrecta o tengo mal la ruta de las librerias, queria saber como puedo hacer para validar todos lo campos incluyendo el radiobutton que sea obligatorio seleccionarlo.

dejo codigo para que miren

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Usuarios</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("css/mycss.css");
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation-1.19.1/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation-1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(function(){


jQuery.validator.addMethod("nombre", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-záéóóúàèìòùäëïöüñ\s]+$/i.test(value);
}); 


$("#guardarnuevo").on("click", function()
   {
   
    $("#ModalRegistro").validate
         ({
             rules: 
             {
              Nombres: {required: true, Nombres: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 50},
              Apellidos: {required: true, Apellidos: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 50},
              Identidad: {required: true, digits: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10},
              Correo: {required: true, Correo: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 20},
              Usuario: {required: true, Usuario: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10},
              Password : {required: true, Password: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10}
             },
             messages: 
             {
               Nombres: {required: 'El campo es requerido', Nombres: 'Sólo letras', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 2 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 50 caracteres'},
               Apellidos: {required: 'El campo es requerido', Apellidos: 'Sólo letras', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 2 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 50 caracteres'},
               Identidad: required: 'El campo es requerido', digits: 'Sólo dígitos', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 8 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 10 caracteres'},
               Correo: {required: 'El campo es requerido', Correo: 'El formato de email es incorrecto', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 4 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 20 caracteres'},
               Usuario: {required: 'El campo es requerido', Usuario: 'Sólo letras', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 5 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 10 caracteres'},
               Password:{required: 'El campo es requerido', Usuario: 'Sólo letras', minlength: 'El mínimo permitido son 5 caracteres', maxlength: 'El máximo permitido son 10 caracteres'}
             }
         });
   });

});
</script>

    <!-- Modal para registro de usuarios nuevos -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalRegistro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega Usuarios </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
   <!-- campos para registrar usuarios -->
   <label>Nombres: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Nombres" class="form-control input-sm" name="Nombres" class="required"><br>
    
    <label>Apellidos: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Apellidos" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Apellidos" class="required" ><br>
    
    <label>Identidad: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Identidad" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Identidad" ><br>

    <label>Correo: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Correo" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Correo" ><br>

    <label>Usuario: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Usuario" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Usuario" ><br>
          
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Password" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Password" ><br>

    <label>Nivel de Permiso del Usuario: </label>
      <input type="radio" name="isActive" id="Adminstrador" value="Adminstrador" checked> Adminstrador
      <input type="radio" name="isActive" id="Usuario" value="Usuario"> Usuario


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo" href="Funcion_Ingreso_Usuarios.php"  >
  Agregar
  </button>
     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido @Darklawz, 
Yo te aconsejaría:

1. Poner el script de las validaciones de jQuery, debajo de la etiqueta `</body>` (la que cierra).
2. Pon el atributo '`required`' de los `inputs` sin una clase, es decir:

Código

```
 <input type="text" id="Nombres" class="form-control input-sm" name="Nombres" required>
```

Y se los agregas así para el resto de los `inputs`.